# Select top 5 customers with balance(:name, :balance) value and put other ones with name Other and sum of balance

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Need help with active record query, I have customers table with name and balance fields.

How can I make query that will return 6 values, first 5 is top customers by balance and 6th one is sum of all others?

need to select name and balance, for others it will custom name ''Other

Answer (score 2):

Divide et impera: make two view then put results together

```
select * 
from ( select * from view_top_5 
                                union 
       select * from view_sum )
```

where view_top_5 is view (or a subquery) that gives you the top 5 customers, view_sum is a query giving you the sum. To get "all **others**" you can build your query from this skeleton:

```
-- skeleton for view "view_sum"
select <what you need> 
from mytable 
where customer_id not in (select client_id 
                        from view_top_5)
```

Comment: While it's good answer for `sql` only question, you must provide active record query and active record orm in rails doesnt't support views.

Comment: @Зелёный He isn't obliged to do a view, he can write just nested query putting the "select" directly into from clause.